# Como é possível ter um número de tamanho ilimitado como o BigInteger?

Tags: c#, .net, biginteger

Sabemos que os tipos de dados numéricos têm um tamanho fixo, como 1, 2, 4, 8 e até 16 bytes no `decimal`.

O tipo [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0), segundo a documentação, não tem limite do valor que pode representar. Como ele consegue ter qualquer valor? Como sempre cabe? Qual é o tamanho do dado?

E porque não tem um `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Começando pelo fim, o `decimal` não é suficiente? Ele vai de -79.228.162.514.264.337.593.543.950.335 até 79.228.162.514.264.337.593.543.950.335, principalmente para valores monetários está bom, não? Acho que atende até o Zimbabue nos piores dias.

O `BigInteger` pode ser usado para operações bem pontuais e pode ter algum caso em que é necessário valores muito grandes, que nem mesmo `double` pode representar bem.

A técnica básica é parecida com a do tipo `string`, ele tem tamanho variável para acomodar todos os bits necessários para representar o número desejado. Então se o número é pequeno ele usa alguns pouco bytes, se ele precisa de um número muito grande precisa de mais bytes.

Então, apesar de ser uma `struct`, ele faz alocação no *heap* para o *array*. Por isso que em código eficiente precisa olhar para os detalhes de implementação. Talvez no futuro consigam fazer sem alocar no *heap*.

Ele é imutável, então se mudar o número em uma variável outro objeto é criado com o tamanho necessário.

Basicamente é um *array* de inteiros (sem sinal). No [código fonte dele](https://source.dot.net/#System.Runtime.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs,33) podemos ver:

```
internal readonly uint[]? _bits;
```

Ali vai armazenando os números. Sempre que 32 bits não forem suficientes ele usa mais um elemento com mais 32 bits com uma escala maior (multiplica por 2 elevado a 32). Não vou entrar em todos os detalhes, se quiser pode dar uma olhada no fonte.

Comment: Sobra ....The budget comprises $57 052 700 000 charged ... https://www.zim.gov.zw/index.php/en/news-room/latest-news/492-government-funding-approved,-takes-effect ... ri muito :)

Comment: É que eles cortam zeros quase semanalmente :D